# Flutter - how to scroll a ListView automatically to make a partially visible Flat Button completely visible

Tags: flutter, dart

My App is a simple AppBar and a horizontal scrollable ListView of ten FlatButtons.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PjIL.png)

As you can see there is a partially visible FlatButton.

I want to scroll the ListView programatically when user press the partially visible FlatButton, to make this one completely visible.

How can i do that?

I attach my code here:

```
class _DashboardScreenState extends State<DashboardScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('FlutterApp'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: 70.0,
        child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: 10,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => _scrollableList(context, index),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget _scrollableList (BuildContext context, int index){
  return Container( 
    child: FlatButton(
      color: Colors.white,
      textColor: Colors.red,
      onPressed: (){},
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)
      ),
      child: Text('data $index'),
    )
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ScrollablePositionedList` from [`flutter_widgets](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_widgets) plugin to achieve this.

Create you ListView as below:

```dart
ItemScrollController _scrollController = ItemScrollController();

ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
  itemScrollController: _scrollController,
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  itemCount: 10,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => _scrollableList(context, index),
)
```

on tap of button scroll to that button as below:

```dart
onPressed: (){
_scrollController.scrollTo(index: index, duration: Duration(seconds: 1));
}
```

let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: It works, but at the same time it has a huge disadvantage: When you press the button, it scrolls to the left margin of the screen, thus hiding the elements on the left for the user.

To work properly you must position the pressed button in the center of the scroll area to let the user know if there are more elements availables on both sides.

Comment: try index as `index: index > 1? index - 2: 0,`. it will show at least 2 buttons before the  clicked button

Comment: It is a better approach, but still has the same problem. It scrolls exactly to the left side of the indexed button and it is not intuitive that there are more elements beyond index-2

Comment: in that case you can manually find the location of button in the list and scroll until the button and it's next button's half potion is visible... but keep it mind that you have to do it manually

Comment: If you use _scrollController.scrollTo with an `alignment` value of slightly more than 0, the item won't scroll all the way to the left.